# Are label removed in bootstrap-4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Earlier there were component named `label` in bootstrap, see documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels) and example below:

```
<h3>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h3>
```

I am not able to find these in [bootstrap-4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components), are these removed, any way to get this with bootstrap-4.

Answer (score 5):

Since the final v. 4 of bootstrap, labels (and tags) have been renamed to badges https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/

Answer (score 4):

It seems, labels has been made tags now, see [docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#labels-badges-and-tags). Documentation of tags [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tag/).

```
<h1>Example heading <span class="tag tag-default">New</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

In 'https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#labels-badges-and-tags' they claim, 'badge'-component was dropped and 'label' was renamed in 'tag' (but well: *alpha*!);

In 'https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#labels-and-badges', there is no 'tag' any more.

No 'label' can be found in the Components section.
No 'tag' can be found in the Components section.

With a search for ".label" you will find

- Progress / Labels (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/progress/#labels)
- Forms / Checkboxes and radios > without Labels (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#without-labels)
- Forms / Layout > Form grid > Horizontal form > Horizontal form label sizing (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#horizontal-form-label-sizing)
- Button group / Basic example > Ensure correct role and provide a label (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/button-group/#ensure-correct-role-and-provide-a-label)

You'll find **Badges** in Components again.
So, at the moment 'Label' and 'Tag' components have still been replaced with 'badges'.

And if you want to have outlined labels, get back to your own label (here with SASS):

```sass
.label
    display: inline-block
    font-size: 11px
    font-weight: 600
    padding: 3px 6px
    border: 1px solid transparent
    min-width: 10px
    line-height: 1
    color: #fff
    text-align: center
    white-space: nowrap
    vertical-align: middle
    border-radius: 99999px
    &.label-outlined
        background-color: transparent
        &.label-primary
            border-color: #2196F3
            color: #2196F3
        &.label-success
            border-color: #64DD17
            color: #64DD17
```

Answer (score 2):

now it is renamed as **badge**.use it like below example:

```
<span class="badge badge-primary">Primary</span>
<span class="badge badge-secondary">Secondary</span>
<span class="badge badge-success">Success</span>
<span class="badge badge-danger">Danger</span>
<span class="badge badge-warning">Warning</span>
<span class="badge badge-info">Info</span>
<span class="badge badge-light">Light</span>
<span class="badge badge-dark">Dark</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing from the above will work if you are using latest Bootstrap's  5.2. This is the correct approach:

```
<span class="badge text-bg-primary">Primary</span>
<span class="badge text-bg-secondary">Secondary</span>
<span class="badge text-bg-success">Success</span>
<span class="badge text-bg-danger">Danger</span>
<span class="badge text-bg-warning">Warning</span>
<span class="badge text-bg-info">Info</span>
<span class="badge text-bg-light">Light</span>
<span class="badge text-bg-dark">Dark</span>
```